# VBA autofilter, criteria's from two ActiveX textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I want to make an autofilter to search for a given age interval. I have put in two textboxes (ActiveX), in the first one you should be able to write the lower age limit, and in the second one the upper age limit.

The code looks like this (when I don't have Textbox2.value as the upper limit, the code works perfectly)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()


If IsNumeric(TextBox1) And IsNumeric(TextBox2) Then
    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$1000").AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:=">=" & TextBox1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TextBox2.Value
    Sheets("filter").Select

End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried starting it with just; which didn't seem to work either.

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox1) Then
```

Any ideas or possibly better ways to do it?

Comment: The english alphabet has 26 letters (A-Z) but you are filtering on field 27? What should happen when `textbox2.value` is less than `textbox1.value`?

Comment: Field 27 refers to a column not a letter? Could you elaborate? :)

Comment: When using `A1:Z1000` you are referring to a range in the first `26` columns, but you are trying to filter by the `27th` column. Either extend the range e.g. `A1:AA1000` or use a `Field` from `1 to 26`.

Answer (score 1):

### Filter Trouble

- The complete code goes into the `filter` sheet code. Adjust the
  constants to fit your needs. Remove the `Debug.Print` lines when done
  testing.
- Avoid using `Select` and `Activate` if possible.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBoxChange
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    TextBoxChange
End Sub

Sub TextBoxChange()

    Const filterSheetName As String = "data"
    Const filterRangeAddress As String = "A1:E10"
    Const filterField As Long = 5

Debug.Print "Before:  " & TextBox1.Value, TextBox2.Value
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1) And IsNumeric(TextBox2) Then
Debug.Print "Between: " & TextBox1.Value, TextBox2.Value
        If TextBox1.Value <= TextBox2.Value Then
Debug.Print "After:   " & TextBox1.Value, TextBox2.Value
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(filterSheetName) _
              .Range(filterRangeAddress).AutoFilter _
                Field:=filterField, Criteria1:=">=" & TextBox1.Value, _
                Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & TextBox2.Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```